# Update post counts (published, draft, unattached) in admin interface

Tags: posts, admin, filters, permissions, users

I am working on a multi-user WordPress setup and have made it so a particular type of user can only see and interact with posts, images, pages etc that they have authored. The code to make this happen looks like this:

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'current_author_posts');

function current_author_posts($query) {

    if ($query->is_admin && current_user_can('artist')) {
        global $user_ID;
        $query->set('author', $user_ID);
    }

    return $query;
}
```

This works well within the admin interface but leaves all of the post counts displaying incorrectly:

[image: image that shows incorrect post counts within WordPress]

Are you aware of any filters or hooks to manipulate these figures and be correct across posts, pages, media and custom post types?

Many thanks.

Comment: `wp_count_posts` [filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_count_posts/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got this almost working, but refinements are needed to fit the specifics of the question and to deal with Attachments and Post-Types differently (see comments in code)...

---

First, I think it's worth noting how I found the filter:
`apply_filters( 'views_' . $screen->id, $views )`

- inspect element
  [image: subsubsub]
- do a global search in `/wp-admin` and `/wp-includes` for *subsubsub* (funny class name, btw)...
- and here it is: `/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php`

---

```
foreach( array( 'edit-post', 'edit-page', 'edit-movie', 'upload' ) as $hook )
    add_filter( "views_$hook" , 'wpse_30331_custom_view_count', 10, 1);

function wpse_30331_custom_view_count( $views ) 
{
    global $current_screen;
    switch( $current_screen->id ) 
    {
        case 'edit-post':
            $views = wpse_30331_manipulate_views( 'post', $views );
            break;
        case 'edit-page':
            $views = wpse_30331_manipulate_views( 'page', $views );
            break;
        case 'edit-movie':
            $views = wpse_30331_manipulate_views( 'movie', $views );
            break;
        case 'upload':
            $views = wpse_30331_manipulate_views( 'attachment', $views );
            break;
    }
    return $views;
}

function wpse_30331_manipulate_views( $what, $views )
{
    global $user_ID, $wpdb;

    /*
     * This is not working for me, 'artist' and 'administrator' are passing this condition (?)
     */
    if ( !current_user_can('artist') ) 
        return $views;

    /*
     * This needs refining, and maybe a better method
     * e.g. Attachments have completely different counts 
     */
    $total = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE (post_status = 'publish' OR post_status = 'draft' OR post_status = 'pending') AND (post_author = '$user_ID'  AND post_type = '$what' ) ");
    $publish = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_author = '$user_ID' AND post_type = '$what' ");
    $draft = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'draft' AND post_author = '$user_ID' AND post_type = '$what' ");
    $pending = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'pending' AND post_author = '$user_ID' AND post_type = '$what' ");

    /*
     * Only tested with Posts/Pages
     * - there are moments where Draft and Pending shouldn't return any value
     */
    $views['all'] = preg_replace( '/\(.+\)/U', '('.$total.')', $views['all'] ); 
    $views['publish'] = preg_replace( '/\(.+\)/U', '('.$publish.')', $views['publish'] ); 
    $views['draft'] = preg_replace( '/\(.+\)/U', '('.$draft.')', $views['draft'] ); 
    $views['pending'] = preg_replace( '/\(.+\)/U', '('.$pending.')', $views['pending'] ); 

    // Debug info
    //echo 'Default counts: <pre>'.print_r($views,true).'</pre>';
    //echo '<hr><hr>';
    //echo 'Query for this screen of this post_type: <b>'.$what.'</b><pre>'.print_r($wp_query,true).'</pre>';

    return $views;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this one. Saved my ass. I have a question though: is it possible to remove the menu contained in .subsubsub completely?

Comment: Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 4):

As of writing, this functionality now resides in the class WP_List_Table, in the method "views()".

The filter now looks like this:

```
$views = apply_filters( "views_{$this->screen->id}", $views );
```

$views will contain an array of each list element:

```
[19-Feb-2016 11:43:44 UTC] Array
(
  [all] => <a href="link_to_view" class="current">Alle <span class="count">(1)</span></a>
  [trash] => <a href="link_to_view">Trash <span class="count">(94)</span></a>
  [confirmed] => <a href="link_to_view">Confirmed <span class="count">(1)</span></a>
)
```

You can hook it up at the current_screen hook with a priority >10:

```
add_action( 'current_screen', function ( $current_screen ) {
        if ($current_screen->id === 'edit-my_page')
            add_filter( "views_{$current_screen->id}", 'list_table_views_filter' );
    }, 20);

function list_table_views_filter( array $view ) {
    error_log(print_r($view, true));
    return $view;
}
```

You can then add/change/remove upon elements in the list.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post, but I have run across it several times looking for a better solution, so I figured I'd add a little something to the mix.  Until today, I have been parsing out each individual number from the strings filtered by `view_{$screen->id}`.  But, I just learned these numbers are parsed in at line [248 of class-wp-posts-list-table.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.4/src/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php#L284).  This `view_{$screen->id}` filter is supposed to be used to *add* and *remove* views, not change the numbers (stupid me).

The function that does all the calculating of the numbers in the parenthesis of the view string is `wp_count_posts()`.  And, its got [a filter with the same name](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_count_posts/) that's been around since [version 3.7.0](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/since/3.7.0/) (released on October 24, 2013—two years after this question was asked).

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options. Let's assume that your custom post type key is "arts-and-crafts-movement"

**OPTION 1**

Using the hook `views_{$this->screen->id}` here:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/views_this-screen-id/

You should hook like this :

```
add_filter( 'views_edit-arts-and-crafts-movement', 'filter_list_table_views', 10 );
```

Then you should add somewhere a function called `filter_list_table_views` to filter the views:

```
function filter_list_table_views( $views ){

   // your counting logic here

   return $views;
}
```

**OPTION 2**

Using the hook `wp_count_posts` here:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_count_posts/

```
add_action( 'current_screen', function ( $screen ) {
            
    if( $screen->id == 'edit-arts-and-crafts-movement' ){
            
        add_filter( 'wp_count_posts', 'filter_list_table_counts' );

    }
});

function filter_list_table_counts( $counts ){

   // your counting logic here

   return $counts;
}
```